# Get all objects that exist in two collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm building a Laravel page on which I want to show a list of lessons. Which lessons should be on the page is filtered by three criteria (of which all should be true):

1. The lesson is active, ie "where('active', true)". Simple enough.
2. The lesson is part of a track that the user has chosen. Models are set up with belongsToMany() (it is a many-to-many relationship), so I can get these lessons by a simple $track->lessons.
3. This is where it gets tricky. Some lessons should only be visible to users with certain titles (ie there is a many to many between titles and lessons). I can get the lessons with the correct title requirement using Auth::user()->title->lessons.

Question is how I get all this together. The best I've come up with this far is the following:

```
$title = Auth::user()->title;
$lessons = Lesson::where('active', true)
    ->whereIn('id', $track->lessons->pluck('id'))
    ->where(function ($query) use($title) {
      $query->whereIn('id', $title->lessons->pluck('id'))->orWhere('limited_by_title', false);
    })
    ->get();
```

...which is crap ugly, clearly suboptimal and (for some reason I really don't understand) also won't work (I don't get the lessons my title entitles me to in my list). Been struggling for quite some hours now, I get the feeling that I'm overcomplicating, first plucking id's and then using them in a whereIn() can't possibly be a good way of doing this.

So I can easily enough get a collection of lessons in the track, and I can get a collection of lessons belonging to the title, but how do I get all objects that exist in both those collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `whereHas()` is the answer to your concerns about plucking IDs. Instead of running additional queries to retrieve IDs, `whereHas()` will attach the constraint to the original query as a subquery on the related tables.

Breaking the query down to its parts:

1: Answered

2: Assuming the inverse of $track->lessons is $lesson->tracks, and $track is coming from code you didn't include:

```php
$lessons = Lesson::whereHas('tracks', function ($query) use ($track) {
            $query->where('id', $track->id);
        })
```

3: Assuming the inverse of $title->lessons is $lesson->titles:

```php
$lessons = Lesson::where(function ($query) use ($title) {
                         $query->whereHas('titles', function ($query) use ($title) {
                             $query->where('id', $title->id);
                         })
                               ->orWhere('limited_by_title', false);
                     })
```

Combined back into one:

```php
    $track = ???;
    $title = Auth::user()->title;
    $lessons = Lesson::where('active', true)
                     ->whereHas('tracks', function ($query) use ($track) {
                         $query->where('id', $track->id);
                     })
                     ->where(function ($query) use ($title) {
                         $query->whereHas('titles', function ($query) use ($title) {
                             $query->where('id', $title->id);

                         })
                               ->orWhere('limited_by_title', false);
                     })
                     ->get();
```

If this still doesn't give the results you were expecting, you can examine the full query being run by replacing `get()` with `toSql()`. Sometimes working from the ORM as a starting point instead of the SQL can lead you down the wrong path. For even more detail to debug and understand the queries being run, you can enable query logging: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#listening-for-query-events

Comment: Ha! After a good nights sleep it turned out that my original code (the one in the question) actually worked. After hours of pulling my hair it seems I unintentionally inactivated the one lesson that my title should give me permission to :-)

However, your solution seems to be a better one performance-wise (no plucking) so obviously I will use that one instead. Also big thanks for the toSql() tip. I feel much more at home with pure SQL code than with this ORM that is a completely new world to me.

Comment: @DanielMalmgren in that case, I've added a link to the documentation which shows you how to listen for database queries. You can use it to log queries, which helped me a lot in understanding how the ORM turned methods into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

intead of where use whereHas on "titles" relationship

```
$title = Auth::user()->title;
$lessons = Lesson::where('active', true)
          ->whereIn('id', $track->lessons->pluck('id'))
          ->whereHas('titles',function ($query) use($title) {
                   $query->whereIn('id', $title->pluck('id')) 
                         ->orWhere('limited_by_title', false);
           })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all complicated, **really complicated**. Your table structure needs serious modification to make it easier.

However, considering you don't want to go down that road, you could do it simpler by using **join**

Assuming you have following table structure:

- users
- titles (has user_id foreign key)
- lessons (has title_id foreign key)
- tracks (has lesson_id foreign key)

  ```
  $trackName = $request->input('track_name');
  $title = Auth::user()->title;
  $lessons = Lesson::join('tracks', 'lessons.id', '=', 'tracks.lesson_id')
      ->join('titles', 'lessons.title_id', '=', 'titles.id')
      ->where('lessons.active', true)
      ->where('tracks.track_name', $trackName)
      ->where(function ($query) use($title) {
        $query->where('titles.id', $title->id)->orWhere('lessons.limited_by_title', false);
      });

  dd($lessons);
  ```

That is of course if your users table and titles have one to one relationship otherwise pluck all title_ids and use `whereIn` instead of `where` for titles.id query.

I hope you have enough understanding of laravel framework to understand and implement this solution.

Sorry, I don't have enough time to proofread or give more details.
Good luck!

Good luck if you need pagination after that :p I doubt simple `->paginate()` will work :D

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned in my question, both lessons-tracks and lessons-titles are many-to-many relations, so titles doesn't have user_id and lessons doesn't have title_id (there are a lesson_title and a lesson_track table inbetween.

Comment: Yup missed that, in that case, maybe you want to make a middle table as suggested by Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many to facilitate the query?